# Deployment of php jqm mobile application on tablet/mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, deployment

I have tried using phonegap , but the php scripts do not work?
Any other alternatives as to how the php jqm applications are deployed on tablet for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is meant to run on Proper Computer/Server as its a Server Side Language. So you need additional Software as the Browser does not have the ability to Interpret the PHP Language by Itself.

However its not a dead end if you wish to run PHP and JQM on a Device by itself.

On Android you can try **KSWEB: server + PHP + MySQL** Software which turns the device into a web server and includes PHP

Out of interest i just tested this software and it works. If you have an Android device download and install the software. The web server starts automatically. Transfer your whole folder (jqm+php scripts you have) in the htdocs folder on the phone, open a browser and type (**localhost:8080/the-name-of-the-folder**) and your jqm + php scripts will run ok.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb&hl=en

Alternatively Check Ubuntu touch, http://www.ubuntu.com/phone i think you can install anything on that like a LAMP server which includes PHP. Its a good choice because stuff like that is free. except for the device.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and let you know..